# Kendo UI for angular 2 Window component

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-window

In the original Kendo UI there is something called kendo ui window, a widget that lets you create dynamic windows in your html.
(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index)

Does anyone know if the Kendo UI for angular 2 will also include this feature?
If yes, when?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the existing KendoUI Angular2 components : http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/

You can then check out the Roadmap they display on this panel : http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/ and notice that the window component is not going to be available soon...

Maybe you can get something out of the popup component for your needs : http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/popup/

Comment: that's a very sad thing to hear. yeah, I saw these posts before but hoped someone knows otherwise. thanks anyway

Comment: @RonAvraham idea is already posted here - http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback/suggestions/17597812-window-component

Comment: @Sanket I know, I posted this idea :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Dialog component](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialog/), which handles the scenario of a modal window, with (optional) actions that the user can take.

Comment: That's not help me. this dialog blurs the entire screen, has no minimize or maximize buttons, and you can't drag this window to another place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to integrate the older kendo window component(jQuery/ng 1.x) in kendo angular 2? Here is the official documentation to mix both worlds. [http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/](http://Kendo%20UI%20for%20jQuery%20Integration)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [Window](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/window/) component from the kendo-angular team. Was introduced in `v2.0.0 (2018-01-12)` to the Dialog components.